# Grouping few of many sourceSets having exactly same configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-productflavors, android-sourcesets

Lets say I have the following `sourceSets`:

```
sourceSets {
    flavor1 {
        assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor1']
        res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor1']
    }
    flavor2 {
        assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor2']
        res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor2']
    }
    flavor3 {
        assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor1']
        res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor1']
    }
    flavor4 {
        assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor2']
        res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor2']
    }
}
```

If you notice `flavor1` and `flavor3` have same srcDirs and so does `flavor2` and `flavor4`.

---

#### Trying Possibility#1

I was trying to figure out if there is a way to avoid the redundancy by using something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    flavor1, flavor3 {
        assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor1']
        res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor1']
    }
    flavor2, flavor4 {
        assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor2']
        res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor2']
    }
}
```

The above does not work (already tried). Looking for something similar so that i can just provide a common set of `sourceDirs` for a set of flavors. Anyone tried doing something similar and can provide some pointers?

---

#### Trying Possibility#2

Does the name of `sourceSets` need to be same as that of flavors?

Can i name the `sourceSets` separately and then map them to `productFlavors` like this?

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
      sourceset = "src1"
    }
    flavor2 {
      sourceset = "src2"
    }
    flavor3 {
      sourceset = "src1"
    }
    flavor4 {
      sourceset = "src2"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    src1 {
    }
    src2 {
    }
}
```

---

#### Trying Possibility#3

Can the sourcesets be dynamically assigned via tasks somehow to achieve the same stuff?

---

### UPDATE

**Douglas's** answer sort of helped me get very close to what i was looking for eventually (reducing the code in build.gradle). He used Possibility#3 above. Thanks Douglas! Any better alternative from bounty hunters is still welcome (something closer to possibilities #1 and #2 above). If nothing comes up the bounty is Douglas's already when the period ends as I've accepted his answer. But still will remain optimistic about finding a better alternative.

Comment: Could you maybe use two `flavorDimensions`? http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants

Comment: thought of that but failing to figure out how it will help in this scenario

Comment: What are the differences between flavor1 and flavor3 and between flavor2 and flavor4? From what we see above it looks like they're identical...

Comment: resources and assets are different (not minimal, they change the entire functionality as assets include the database)

Comment: But these are different between all 4 flavors, right? That would mean that you really need one `flavorDimension`s with 4 flavors - and then introducing another `flavorDimension` would only make matters worse...

Comment: yes, that's what stopped me from thinking more about dimensions

Comment: In that case, sorry for wasting your time - let's hope someone else has a better idea.

Comment: What about setting the root of sourceSets flavor3 to refer to flavor1? sourceSets.flavor3.root = sourceSets.flavor1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229514/let-two-flavors-use-the-same-sourceset

Comment: @jmols how can i use `.root` in this case? I have only `assets` and `res' to mention in the `sourceSets`. Can you help with an example of what you are thinking of that would help in this case?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is that 300 flavors?

Comment: i know it sounds strange. But i have variations based on change in resources and assets :) and have designed the project such that replacing these will give you a whole different app. so 300 is not the end of it. I'm probably going to have more than 1k by the end of year.

Comment: Interesting administrative challenge in the Google Play Developer Console :)

Comment: its a pain, also think about other stores

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were also pretty close with your first possibility:

```
sourceSets {
    [flavor1, flavor3].each {
        it.assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor1']
        it.res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor1']
    }
    [flavor2, flavor4].each {
        it.assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor2']
        it.res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor2']
    }
}
```

The above doesn't look nice in IDEA editor, a lot of warnings are shown. You can set the type if you want to get code completion:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet
android {
    sourceSets {
        [flavor2, flavor4].each { AndroidSourceSet ss ->
            ss.assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor2']
            ss.res.srcDirs = ['repo-res/flavor2']
        }
    }
}
```

Another trick: this way the definition of the flavor is co-located with the source set listing.

```
android
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            applicationId "flavor1.app.id"
        }
        flavor2 {
            applicationId "flavor2.app.id"
        }
        [flavor1, flavor2].each {
            sourceSets[it.name].assets.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor1']
            sourceSets[it.name].res.srcDirs = ['repo-assets/flavor1']
        }
    }
```

Whichever way you go there's also a noteworthy thing about `srcDirs`, [see source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/api/AndroidSourceDirectorySet.java):

```
println assets.srcDirs // say it's [src/flavor/assets]
assets.srcDirs = ['dir1', 'dir2'] // overwrites existing directories: output would be [dir1, dir2]
assets.srcDirs 'dir1', 'dir2' // appends existing directories: output would be [src/flavor/assets, dir1, dir2]
assets.srcDir 'dir1' // appends only one dir, output would be [src/flavor/assets, dir1]
```

Comment: That was neat! I liked it

Comment: I was looking the docs for Groovy, I came to edit my answer to add exactly that.

Comment: OMG! where were you till now? :) Let me give this a try. Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: have another question to improvise this: mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291362/fetching-values-in-build-gradle-from-an-xml-or-csv

Answer (score 2):

I think what @jmols is trying to say in comments is something like this:

Go from structure

```
repo-assets
    flavor1
    flavor2
repo-res
    flavor1
    flavor2
```

to

```
flavor1
    assets
    res
flavor2
    assets
    res
```

and use

```
sourceSets {
    //flavor1.setRoot('flavor1') // default
    //flavor2.setRoot('flavor2') // default
    flavor3.setRoot('flavor1')
    flavor4.setRoot('flavor2')
}
```

See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure for `setRoot` and default structure.
Here's the [source code of `setRoot`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/api/DefaultAndroidSourceSet.java#256), notice that it resets all customizations, that's why it's crucial to match the default structure. Its built-in call is located [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BaseExtension.groovy#114).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to copy flavors (outside of `android {}`):

```
def copyFlavor(flavordest, flavororig) {
    flavordest.resources.srcDirs = flavororig.resources.srcDirs
    flavordest.res.srcDirs = flavororig.res.srcDirs
    flavordest.aidl.srcDirs = flavororig.aidl.srcDirs
    flavordest.java.srcDirs = flavororig.java.srcDirs
    flavordest.assets.srcDirs = flavororig.assets.srcDirs
    flavordest.renderscript.srcDirs = flavororig.renderscript.srcDirs

    // if you don't need all of this, remove them. There are much more too, like `jni` and `jniLibs`
}
```

then call this function on source sets:

```
sourceSets {
    copyFlavor(flavor3, flavor1)  // flavor3 = flavor1
    copyFlavor(flavor4, flavor2)  // flavor4 = flavor2
}
```

Of course, it's only worth if you have many flavors, for only two, the overhead of writing a function is greater.

**Edit:** *adding the project structure I used*

To simplify and not need to specify flavor1 and flavor2 paths, I used the standard structure for flavors:

```
app/
    src/
        androidTest/
        flavor1/
            assets/
            res/
                values/strings.xml
        flavor2/
            assets/
            res/
                values/strings.xml
        main/
            assets/
            java/
            res/
                values/strings.xml
        test/
```

`values.xml` has a string `app_name` with content `"SourceSets"` for `main`, `"SourceSets 1"`for `flavor1` and `"SourceSets 2"` for `flavor2`.

Just define flavor1 and flavor2 path the standard way and copy them later using the function provided.

**Edit 2:** *Things I tried and probably some would work, but none did here (probably I made some stupid mistake from)*

Things I tried and didn't work:

A:
1. `flavor3.root = "flavor1"`
2. `flavor3.root = "flavor1/"`
3. `flavor3.setRoot("flavor1")`
4. `flavor3.setRoot("flavor1/")`
These compiled, but the string resource I had defined to test didn't change.

B:
`flavor3.root = flavor1.root`
This doesn't even compile, `.root` is write-only.

C:
`flavor3.root = flavor1`
This also compiled, but had no effect. Notice it differs from **A** because in **A**, the right-hand-side is a string.

D:
I had the idea of `[].each` too, but when I tried it, I probably made some stupid mistake and it didn't work either:

```
    [flavor2, flavor4].each {
        it.res.srcDirs = ["flavor2/res"]
        it.resources.srcDirs = ["flavor2/res"]
        it.assets.srcDirs = ["flavor2/assets"]
    }
```

The last one I had some hope, but couldn't manage. Then I stuck to the `copyFlavor` function. All above I also tried with prepending `src` (e.g., `src/flavor1`), unsuccessful.

Comment: i do have a lot of flavors, around 300. This looks like something that will work for me. I'll give it a try and update in a few hours.

Comment: I'll update the answer with the project structure I used in 20-30 minutes (I'm on mobile now).

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Did it work? May I add anything to help?

Comment: You can also do with variables, but it will be cumbersome in the same way as your original build.gradle.

Comment: Haven't tried yet. Reached home a while ago. I'll try tonight and get back. But i am optimistic about this working out. :) Thanks a lot for the input ... :)

Comment: Cheers! That worked! Thanks a lot. I'll accept the answer but will wait for the bounty award to automatically be awarded to you when the period ends. Meanwhile if someone comes up with a better answer I might need to change it. Hope that is OK with you. But, I highly doubt if anyone would (bounty is yours). But will still remain optimistic about it. Thanks again for the valuable input.

Comment: btw, any clue on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105494/localizing-string-resources-added-via-build-gradle-using-resvalue ?

Comment: Cool! I have a personal project, learn Android hunting hard questions. It took me a while to figure out that solution, but it was worth. I'll check this other one as soon as I have some time.

Comment: have another question to improvise this: mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291362/fetching-values-in-build-gradle-from-an-xml-or-csv